# How to extract all negative subsequences using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I need to extract all negative subsequences from source sequence. For example, I have:

> { -2, -2, 5, 9, 1, -6, -7, -2, 5, 11, -2 }

In the results I want to get these sequences:

> {-2, -2}, {-6,-7, -2} and {-2}

Is it possible to solve the task using LINQ?

Comment: I solved the task using for loop. Unfortunately, I have not any ideas how I can solve it using LINQ :(

Comment: @elias: Why would you want to use LINQ if you don't know how to solve it? Chances are that you wont be able to read the code later, which in turn make it harder to maintain it. Always go for the most readable approach when performance is not an issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a key variable to differentiate which ones are negative.

```
var list = new[] { -2, -2, 5, 9, 1, -6, -7, -2, 5, 11, -2 };
var key = 1;
var arr = list.Select(x => new { x, key = x < 0 ? key : (key++ * 0) })
    .Where(x => x.key > 0)
    .GroupBy(x => x.key)
    .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.x).ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

Without `Where`, `GroupBy` and `Select`, the result will look like:

[image]

Then we just need to take only positive key, group them by key and take only the value.

Output

```
{ -2, -2  }
{ -6, -7, -2  }
{ -2  }
```

[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UxSWod)

Comment: Sorry, the screenshot were using v as property name in the anonymous type, then I changed it to x

Comment: Ya got there is x.x not a x.v rgt